# How do I get other advertisements to work in google sites? eg Adbrite code not linking pic

Tags: javascript, html, ads, sites

I use the html box and paste the code adbrite supplies. I know nothing about code! But it seems to parse, no red lines. Google says javascript cannot link to images, so does this mean the ad will not work? my site is www.blisstropic.tv the ad is under the header. The code entered in the box is below. Is there an app or way to get other ads working? I am banned from adsense for no reason pretty much! I used to like google, now I am thinking, er no!

```
<!-- Begin: adBrite, Generated: 2012-09-09 15:57:20  -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var AdBrite_Title_Color = '00FF80';
var AdBrite_Text_Color = 'FF6FCF';
var AdBrite_Background_Color = '000000';
var AdBrite_Border_Color = '66B5FF';
var AdBrite_URL_Color = 'FFFFFF';
var AdBrite_Page_Url = '';
try{var AdBrite_Iframe=window.top!=window.self?2:1;var AdBrite_Referrer=document.referrer==''?document.location:document.referrer;AdBrite_Referrer=encodeURIComponent(AdBrite_Referrer);}catch(e){var AdBrite_Iframe='';var AdBrite_Referrer='';}
</script>
<span style="white-space:nowrap;"><script type="text/javascript">document.write(String.fromCharCode(60,83,67,82,73,80,84));document.write(' src="http://ads.adbrite.com/mb/text_group.php?sid=2209268&zs=3436385f3630&ifr='+AdBrite_Iframe+'&ref='+AdBrite_Referrer+'&purl='+encodeURIComponent(AdBrite_Page_Url)+'" type="text/javascript">');document.write(String.fromCharCode(60,47,83,67,82,73,80,84,62));</script>
<a target="_top" href="http://www.adbrite.com/mb/commerce/purchase_form.php?opid=2209268&afsid=1"><img src="http://files.adbrite.com/mb/images/adbrite-your-ad-here-banner.gif" style="background-color:#66B5FF;border:none;padding:0;margin:0;" alt="Your Ad Here" width="11" height="60" border="0" /></a></span>
<!-- End: adBrite -->
```

Comment: I am so proud of myself and the internet! See answer below, this guy Mori is so helpful. You have to make a custom gadget, however Google says it will soon not let you do this at the top of the developer page? Is this a longterm solution?

https://sites.google.com/site/mori79/html-gadgets

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `<script>` tags in the Google Sites HTML box and you are not meant to put your own ads in Google Sites. Google Sites is designed to be a simple web site creator and is not meant for most HTML, attributes, and advanced CSS.